# catch block for promise inside promise,

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I push many promises to an array and then I wait with `Promises.all()` for all them to resolve. yet if I reject one of them, the whole program crashes, instead of getting just an error log or a reject value.

```js
async function waiter(string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var promisesFor300 = [];

    for (let k = 1; k < 300; k++) {
      promisesFor300.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          //do stuff with index
          //resolve or reject
          reject(0);
        }),
      );
    }

    Promises.all(promisesFor300).then(() => {
      resolve("All promises finished without rejection");
    });
  });
}

console.log(await waiter(myStr));
```

if `reject(0)` is called, here is the error we get

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "0".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

**What I tried**

```js
try {
  console.log(await waiter(myStr));
} catch(e) {}
```

I also tried to put some try and catch statements inside `for` loop, yet it still didnt seem to have any affect.

So If i get any rejection I want to do a single action by catching that with `catch` or something else, instead of having the whole program exit by calling rejection error.

**Update:**

```
async function waiter(string) {
    var promisesFor300 = [];

    for (let k = 1; k < 300; k++) {
      promisesFor300.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          //do stuff with index
          //resolve or reject
          reject(0);
        }),
      );
    }

    return Promise.all(promisesFor300).then(() => {
      return myValueFromCalls;
    });
 
}

console.log(await waiter(myStr))
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` never executes because you're returning on line #2. You certainly don't need that outer `new Promise()`

Comment: That was a bracket issue, ```Promise.all()``` is also inside the returning function. so it runs and i confirm it. yet that is not the question OP asked for. @Phil

Comment: the provided link does NOT answer my question. I ask the line to place the ```catch()``` block

Comment: Again, you do not need the outer `new Promise()`. Remove that, construct your `promisesFor300` array and `return Promise.all(promisesFor300)`

Comment: no that is NOT correct. I need that outer new Promise to return the value as a whole from different promises/functions inside and also to WAIT for them to finish @Phil

Comment: and what about the question ?..

Comment: Then use `return Promise.all(promisesFor300).then(() => 'All promises finished without rejection')`. Then, any rejections from `promisesFor300` will bubble out to the caller. What you're missing right now is any call to that outer promise `reject()`. Rejections in the inner promises are unhandled

Comment: I did what you said and put the update. it works and i dont need outer return indeed. yet still if i call ```reject()``` inside ```push```'s promise, the whole program quits with the same error. @Phil

Comment: I just want to be able to handle with a callback or something if there is any ```reject()``` ccall in any of the promises, but with the last update even i get the crash with error log. @Phil

Comment: You have no rejection handling at all. You'd need `try..catch` around the call to `waiter(myStr)`... `try { console.log(await waiter(myStr)); } catch (err) { console.error('rejection', err); }`

Comment: it's `Promise.all` not `Promises.all` - and you need to put a catch on the `Promise.all` to fix your issue

Comment: Oh, and your `Update:` code is also the more correct way of doing it - though, technically in either case, `waiter` does not need to be `async` since you never `await`